# Laravel 5.2 Multi sms

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, gammu

How to explode multi sms number on laravel 5.2?

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    $mes = new Outbox();
    $mes->DestinationNumber = $request->input('DestinationNumber');
    $explode = explode(' ',$mes->DestinationNumber);
    return $explode;
}
```

Comment: Share `var_dump($mes->DestinationNumber)` please

Comment: can you show what `$request->input('DestinationNumber')` is

Comment: What will be the output you want? Can you give an example.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Laravel related question.

Find the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) from the PHP web and use your logic.

It depends how you have `$mes->DestinationNumber` stored and how you want them to return from your function.

```
// CSV to array
$result= explode(',', $mes->DestinationNumber);

// array to CSV
$result= implode(',', $mes->DestinationNumber);
```

Check before you convert and return your result:

```
var_dump($mes->DestinationNumber);
// your logic here ..
var_dump($result);exit;
```